# How to limit jar file execution in shell script (need to stop process if running more than 5)

Tags: shell-script, scheduling

I am executing one `jar` file, now I have to set a limit of execution is 5 (Max 5 process of that `jar` execution permitted) if 6th is invoked via `crontab` it should be blocked.

e.g.: `abc.jar` file is running and a new instance started every 5 minutes. If I have 5 instance or processID of 5, it should limit 6th.

Kindly help

Comment: Although you mentioned `crontab`, the actual environment in which all this happens is not quite clear. Can you show us the `crontab` entry? What do you mean with "it should limit 6th"? Does it mean the next instance should not start at all and only on the next `cron` iteration a new attempt should be made, or should the next instance be put "on hold" and start as soon as one of the running five is terminated? What OS flavor and version are you running?

Comment: how is the jar file being executed?  If it's being executed from a script, the check for the number already running should be incorporated into the script (test ```ps -ef | grep abc.jar | grep -v grep | wc -l``` for instance... may need to be made more specific).  If it's being executed manually, the check for pre-existing processes will probably need to be done within the main routine of the jar itself.